# Show that $\{(x,\sin(1/x)) : x∈(0,1] \} \cup \{(0,y) : y ∈ [-1,1] \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$ using sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Usual metric.

The abridged definitions we were just given are:

Convergent Sequence: A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $X$ converges to $x_0$ if for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n, x_0) \lt \varepsilon$ for each $n \geq n_0$.

Closed set: A set $F$ in a metric space $X$ is closed if and only if every convergent sequence in $F$ converges to a point in $F$.

---

This is the last question of a problem set to study for class. The definitions we are using are very standard for an Intro to Topology course, I just don't understand how to apply them properly yet. Would anyone be able to lend me a hand? Or show me how to start?

Comment: Make some attempts here. I presume you are allowed to use continuity of $\sin$, so any sequence that converges to $(x_0,y_0)$ with $x_0>0$ you should be able to handle easily (i.e., what must you show in this case?). Next, suppose you have a sequence converging to $(0,y_0)$. What must you show in this case?

Comment: So for $(0,y_0)$ I have to show that $(0,y_0)$ is still in the set correct? So would assuming it doesn't and try to reach a contradiction work?

Comment: Yes, you have to show that if $(x_n,y_n)$ is a sequence in your set converging to $(0,y_0)$, then $(0,y_0)$ is in your set. Which means what?

Comment: From that, I think I should use the definition of convergence. So I know that if $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $(0,y_0)$, then $x_n$ converges to $0$ and $y_n$ converges to $y_0$. Wich means that for $ε>0$, there is $n_0$ such that $d(x_n,0)<ε$ and $d(y_n,y_0)<ε$. I'm a bit lost after that...

Comment: Your set is known as the closed topologist's sine curve. There are plenty of questions in this forum dealing with it.

Comment: If $y_0 > 1$, choose $\epsilon :=  (y_0 - 1)^2$. For any $(x_n, y_n)$, you have $d((x_n, y_n), (0, y^*))^2 = x_n^2 + (y_n - y^*)^2 \ge (1 - y^*)^2 = \epsilon$. This shows that your sequence does not converge toward $(0, y^*)$.

Comment: I got it, thank you all very much.

Comment: @ssvnormandysr2 Then you should write an answer to your own question. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .

Comment: In my experience, for most of the queries posted here, the original poster doesn't bother to specify the definitions or give any background on the problem.  If your query hadn't already been upvoted, I would have upvoted for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a sequence $(x_n,\sin\frac{1}{x_n})$ converge to some point $(x_0,y_0)$. Since $x_n\ge 0$ and $-1\le y_n\le 1$, we have two cases:

- $x_0=0$

In this case, the limit point falls within $\{(0,y): -1\le y\le 1\}$ because $x_n\ge 0$ and $-1\le y_n\le 1$.

- $x_0>0$

We can write
$$
{
|x_n-x_0|<\epsilon_1\implies |\sin\frac{1}{x_n}-\sin\frac{1}{x_0}|<\epsilon_2
\\
|\sin\frac{1}{x_n}-y_0|<\epsilon_3
}.
$$
From the above inequalities, we conclude by the triangle inequality that
$$
{|\sin\frac{1}{x_0}-y_0|
\\=|\sin\frac{1}{x_n}-y_0-\sin\frac{1}{x_n}+\sin\frac{1}{x_0}|
\\\le|\sin\frac{1}{x_n}-y_0|+|\sin\frac{1}{x_n}-y_0|
\\<\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3
}
,
$$
which yields $\sin\frac{1}{x_0}-y_0$ because both $y_0$ and $\sin\frac{1}{x_0}$ are constant $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ denote the set in question and fix $z \in S$.

First suppose that $z = (x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}))$ for some $x \in (0,1]$. Pick your favourite sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \in (0,1]$ (eg. $x_n = x + \frac{1}{n}$ for large enough $n$.) ​Since $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ it follows that $\sin(\frac{1}{x_n}) \to \sin(\frac{1}{x})$. Hence, $(x_n,\sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))$ is a sequence in $S$ which converges to $z$.

Now suppose that $z = (0,y)$ for some $y \in [-1,1]$. Since the function $\sin$ is continuous, an Intermediate Value Theorem argument implies that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, there exists some $a_n \in [n,n+2\pi]$ such that $\sin(a_n) = y$. Let $x_n = \frac{1}{a_n}$ and observe that $x_n \in (0,1]$. Then $x_n \to 0$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{x_n}) \to y$. It follows that $(x_n,\sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))$ is a sequence in $S$ converging to $z$.

Since every point of $S$ is the limit point of some sequence in $S$, it follows that $S$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A: = \{ (x, \sin(\frac{1}{x})) \mid x \in (0, 1] \}$ and $B := \{ (0, y) \mid y \in [-1, 1] \}$.

Fix any sequence $\{a_n\} _{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \{ (x_n , y_n )\} _{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A \cup B$ that converge in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $a = (x,y)$ be the limit point of $\{a_n\}_n$.

Let $N_A := \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid a_n \in A \} $ and $N_B := \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid a_n \in B \}$.

Then, at least one of $N_A$ and $N_B$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{N}$.

Let us assume that the essential case  that $N_A$ is unbounded (otherwise use closeness of $B$) and $x = 0$ (otherwise use continuity of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$) occurs.

Consider the subsequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in N_A}$.
Note that the limit of any subsequence of a convergent sequence $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equal to the limit of $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (you know?).
Since $y_n =  \sin (\frac{1}{x_n})\in [-1 , 1]$ for all $n \in N_A$ and $[-1, 1]$ is closed, we have $y \in [-1, 1]$.

Therefore $a \in B$.

Thus $A\cup B$ is closed under limit of sequence and hence it is closed.